# excel vba - delete all rows except header and subtotal

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following code whereby I have set a range in a filtered list and I want to delete the visible cells. I have offset by 1 because of the header row, but I also have a row at the very bottom of the code with my totals in the last row, how can I delete all visible rows except the very last to keep my totals?

```
With rng
    .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>*" & owner & "*"
    .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

Thanks

Comment: Include the "Totals" row also in `rng`. The total row will not show when you use autofilter as it doesn't meet the autofilter criteria. That ways you will not have to worry about not deleting it. Or have I misunderstood your question...

Comment: The total row always shows as I'm filtering out rows that don't contain certain things. I Suppose I could redo the total row after the deleting has finished but would be nice to get it in the above code somehow

Comment: I should add that the total row actually totals other columns and not the one I'm filtering

Comment: The last row Col 5 is always blank. All cells in my data in Col 5 are strings

Comment: I think I may have a very easy solution for you :) Will the totals always be in row 5?

Comment: They start in row 250 but then I filter so could be anywhere...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59526/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-m0atz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>*" & owner & "*"
ActiveSheet.Rows(250).Hidden = True
.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

Edit: Post Discussion in Chat.

The row address never changes when you autofilter. So simply hide the row after autofilter and you are done :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just adjust position & resize your range accordingly before filtering to exclude the first and last row

```
With r.Offset(1, 0).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 2)
    .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>*" & owner & "*"
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your autofilter criteria but this should give you a start,

```
For x = 2 To Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row - 1
If Sheets("sheet1").Rows(x).Hidden = False Then
    If 1 = 1 Then  ' Replace 1=1 with your autofilter criteria
        Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
    End If
Else
End If
Next x
```

Edit:  Better answers posted in time I took to come up with mine.

Comment: Thanks Myles.  Appreciate the effort